# sql query that searches all columns in two tables, i need to add a another column "AS" to it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is my SQL query that searches all columns in two tables (i didnt make this) i need to add this statement to it

```
, (tblUsers.Forename + ' ' + tblUsers.Surname) AS CleanName
```

but am unsure where to put it, can anyone help me out?
THanks

```
USE [ITAPP]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_SearchAllTables]    Script Date: 07/11/2013 10:57:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_SearchAllTables]
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @where varchar(8000)
declare @sql varchar(8000)
set @sql = 'select * from tblUsers u join tblEquipment e on e.userid = u.id WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( 1= 0 '

select @where = coalesce(@where ,'' ) + ' OR  ' + case when object_name(object_id)  = 'tblUsers' then 'u' else 'e' end + '.[' +  name + '] LIKE ''%' + replace(@SearchStr, '''', '''''') + '%'' '
 from sys.columns where object_id in ( select object_id from sys.objects where name in ( 'tblUsers','tblEquipment' ))
 and collation_name is not null
set @where = coalesce(@where, '') + ')'

print @sql
print @where

exec(@sql + @where)

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change:

```
set @sql = 'select * from tblUsers u join tblEquipment e on e.userid = u.id WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( 1= 0 '
```

to

```
set @sql = 'select u.*,e.*, (u.Forename + '' '' + u.Surname) AS CleanName from tblUsers u join tblEquipment e on e.userid = u.id WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( 1= 0 '
```

Note: you need to delimit the single-quotes..

Answer (score 3):

You're just adding to the select part of the statement on the set @sql line

here's it filled in.

```
USE [ITAPP]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_SearchAllTables]    Script Date: 07/11/2013 10:57:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_SearchAllTables]
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @where varchar(8000)
declare @sql varchar(8000)
set @sql = 'select u.*, e.*, (tblUsers.Forename + '' '' + tblUsers.Surname) AS CleanName from tblUsers u join tblEquipment e on e.userid = u.id WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( 1= 0 '

select @where = coalesce(@where ,'' ) + ' OR  ' + case when object_name(object_id)  = 'tblUsers' then 'u' else 'e' end + '.[' +  name + '] LIKE ''%' + replace(@SearchStr, '''', '''''') + '%'' '
 from sys.columns where object_id in ( select object_id from sys.objects where name in ( 'tblUsers','tblEquipment' ))
 and collation_name is not null
set @where = coalesce(@where, '') + ')'

print @sql
print @where

exec(@sql + @where)

END
```

Probably worth reading a SQL tutorial so you can see how this works:
Heres an example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: This won't work in some DBMSs (e.g. Oracle). You can't `select *` and also define a further list of columns, unless you use a table alias i.e. `select u.*, <more cols>.. from table u`

Comment: thats what i thought but im getting an error becuase of the single quotes Incorrect syntax near ' + u.Surname)  from tblUsers u join tblEquipment e on e.userid = u.id WHERE 1 = 1 AND ( 1= 0 '.

Comment: good point - forgot to alter double-up the quotes inside the string literal! Have also named the tables as per AlexW's point. See the editted version now

Comment: @StevieG Good job the OP has requested this for SQL Server then isnt it

Comment: @SelectDistinct - Yep, would have been even better if he'd done that originally instead of adding it after my comment, wouldn't it

Comment: ok the query runs now but the search query isnt searching against the CleanName field, can i add that criteria to it somehow?

Comment: @AlexW - CleanName isn't actually a field in the database, its an amalgamation of 2 fields with a space between. Could add a separate OR bit to the where clause to search that.
If you add an initial value of the where string as so this should work
`select @where = ' OR u.[Forename] + '' '' + u.[Surname] LIKE ''%' + replace(@SearchStr, '''', '''''') + '%''' 
`

put this line of code in immediately after the line set @sql = 'select ....